# Python 2: why does this function follow with a boolean without if/else conditions?

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean, boolean-logic

Here is the sample code I was given to complete:

```
def is_leap(year):
leap = False

year = int(raw_input())
print is_leap(year)
```

I've managed to solve it through all sample test cases but I don't understand why leap is assigned False when there are no conditions. What is the point of doing that if I have to redefine leap to True or False again based on the conditions?

Conditions:
A year is considered a leap year when:

The year can be evenly divided by 4, is a leap year, unless:

The year can be evenly divided by 100, it is NOT a leap year, unless:

The year is also evenly divisible by 400. Then it is a leap year.

My code:

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False

    if (year % 4 == 0):
       leap = True
    if year % 100 == 0:
        if year % 400 == 0:
            leap = True
        else:
            leap = False
    return leap
year = int(raw_input())
print is_leap(year)
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code, please explain.

Comment: please correct the indentation!

Comment: Is there nay specific reason to use python 2.x

Comment: `why leap is assigned False when there are no conditions.?` because `leap` is the value we are solving for, therefore we need to declare it to python in order to use it, and it can only be binary - true or false. But to answer your question directly, if we don't assigning leap an inital value we get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'leap' referenced before assignment.` Otherwise, the decision to assign leap false is an arbitrary, the author could have also assigned it initially as true, and change the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have two `if` statements that can set the `leap` variable.  But it's completely possible that neither condition will be met, and `leap` needs to have a value in that case or you will get an exception in the `return` statement.

P.S.  No need to make the question specific to Python 2, it's the same in Python 3.

Comment: Apart from the fact that in Python 3 the function is called `input()` not `raw_input()`.

Comment: @BoarGules good point, I missed that.  And also that `print` was a statement and not a function.  But those aren't really part of the question, just support for the code sample.

Comment: Conceded, that wasn't intended as a criticism, only a remark for OP's benefit, since we are obviously helping out a beginner.

Comment: Thank you  very much. What do you mean that print was a statement not a function? I understand the sentence but were you referencing the question title where I mentioned "function"?

Comment: @EnthusiasticGerbil `print` is one of the biggest differences between Python 2 and 3.  In Python 2 it's a statement, and you just list the items you want to print as you did in your question code.  In Python 3 it's a function, so you must pass the things you want to print as parameters within parentheses.  It's one of the easiest ways of knowing which Python version you're targeting.  I wasn't referencing your question title at all.